# field clone limit in html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

how to do clone field limitation in html? i tried using below code, i cannot limit clone its continueing i need to limit clone to 5 field. therefore all other functions are working very well but i cannot do field clone limit using add button. please tell me anyone hows these possible to do?
my entire code is pasted below. please check my error area and clarify the error.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Form</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        
    
    
    
    

    <!-- jQuery CDN -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.2.slim.js" integrity="sha256-OflJKW8Z8amEUuCaflBZJ4GOg4+JnNh9JdVfoV+6biw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    


        <script>
            function BtnAdd()
{
    /*Add Button*/

    var v = $("#TRow").clone().appendTo("#TBody") ;
    $(v).find("input").val('');
    $(v).removeClass("d-none");
    $(v).find("th").first().html($('#TBody tr').length - 0);




}

function BtnDel(v)
{
    /*Delete Button*/
       $(v).parent().parent().remove(); 
       GetTotal();

        $("#TBody").find("tr").each(
        function(index)
        {
           $(this).find("th").first().html(index);
        }

       );
}


        </script>


    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">

    

       <!-- Change action -->
        <form method="POST" action="https://script...." action='server-script.cgi' onsubmit='this.submit();this.reset();return false;'>
            <h4> |Registration Form for M.V Corals </left></h4>
            
            <hr class="double">
            
            
            <p>
                <label for="inv_no"> Reg.No: </label>
            <input type="text" name="inv_no"  value="Auto" readonly="readonly"></p>
            
            <p>
                <label for="cust_nm"> Name of Register:</label>
            <input type="text" name="cust_nm" placeholder="Type Your Name" required=""> </p>
            
            <p>
                <label for="addr"> Address:</label>
            <input type="text" name="addr"    placeholder="Type Your Address" required="" >
            </p>
            
            <p>
                <label for="city"> Mob.No:</label>
            <input type="text" name="city"    placeholder="Type Your Mob.No." required="">
            </p>

            <!--Date of Journey 1: <input type="date" name="inv_dt"  value="dd-mm-yy"> </br>
            Date of Journey 2: <input type="date" name="inv_dt2"  value="dd-mm-yy"> </br>
            Date of Journey 3: <input type="date" name="inv_dt3"  value="dd-mm-yy"> </br> -->

             <h3>Maximum 5 passengers allowed to register as per rule</center> </h3>
             
                            
            <table >
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th >Sl.No.</th>
                        <th >Name of Passenger</th>
                        <th >Age</th>
                        <th >Gender</th>
                        <th >Class</th>
                        <th >DoJ 1</th>
                        <th >DoJ 2</th>
                        <th >DoJ 3</th>
                        <th >                        
                            <button  type="button" class="buttonadd" onclick="BtnAdd()">+</button>
                          
                        </th>

                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody  id="TBody">
                      <tr id="TRow" >
                        <th scope="row">1</th>
                        <td ><input type="text" size="25" name="item_nm" placeholder="Type Your Name" required></td>
                        <td><input type="text" size="1" name="qty" placeholder="Age" required ></td>

                        <td>
                        <select name="rate" required >
                        <option placebolder="Not Selected"></option>
                        <option value="Male">Male</option>
                        <option value="Female">Female</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <select name="amt" required >
                        <option placebolder="Not Selected"></option>
                        <option value="TOKEN">TOKEN</option>
                        <option value="FIRST CLASS">FIRST CLASS</option>
                        <option value="SECOND CLASS">SECOND CLASS</option>
                        <option value="BUNK">BUNK</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <select name="doj1" required  >
                        <option placebolder="Not Selected"></option>
                        <option value="05-07-2023">05-07-2023</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="doj2"disabled="">
                        <option placebolder="Not Selected"></option>
                        <option value="25-06-2023">22.06.2023</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="doj3"disabled="" >
                        <option placebolder="Not Selected"></option>
                        <option value="28-06-2023">22.06.2023</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>

                        <td class="NoPrint"><button type="button"  class="buttondel" onclick="BtnDel(this)">X</button></td>
                      </tr>



                    </tbody>
                  </table>

            <button type="submit" class="submit" >Submit</button>
            <button type="reset" class="reset">Reset</button>
            
            <hr class="double">
            
            
        </form> 
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ...and _what is the error_? ... append to the question.

Comment: I cannot implement clone field limit to 5, i don't need clone above five

Answer (score 1):

Add some logic to BtnAdd() and BtnDel() to count rows and disable/enable add button:

```
function BtnAdd()
{
    /*Add Button*/    
    var v = $("#TRow").clone().appendTo("#TBody") ;
    $(v).find("input").val('');
    $(v).removeClass("d-none");
    $(v).find("th").first().html($('#TBody tr').length - 0);
    
    if($('tbody').find('tr').length > 4){ // <- this
        $('.buttonadd').prop('disabled', true);
    }

}

function BtnDel(v)
{
    /*Delete Button*/
    $(v).parent().parent().remove(); 
       
    if($('tbody').find('tr').length < 5){ // ..and this
        $('.buttonadd').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    GetTotal();

    $("#TBody").find("tr").each(
        function(index)
        {
            $(this).find("th").first().html(index);
        }

    );
       
}
```

See working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8nj5mk7b/3/

Comment: i got it from your code , thank you so much for your contribution @Svela